# Split a quantity into multiple rows with limit on quantity per row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of ids and quantities that looks like this:

```
dbo.Quantity 
id | qty 
-------
1  |  3
2  |  6
```

I would like to split the quantity column into multiple lines and number them, **but with a set limit** (which can be arbitrary) on the maximum quantity allowed for each row.

So for the **value of 2**, expected output should be:

```
dbo.DesiredResult
id | qty |  bucket
---------------
1  |  2  |  1
1  |  1  |  2 
2  |  1  |  2 
2  |  2  |  3 
2  |  2  |  4 
2  |  1  |  5
```

In other words,
Running `SELECT id, SUM(qty) as qty FROM dbo.DesiredResult` should return the original table (dbo.Quantity).

Running
`SELECT id, SUM(qty) as qty FROM dbo.DesiredResult GROUP BY bucket`
should give you this table.

```
id |    qty    | bucket
------------------
1  |     2     | 1
1  |     2     | 2 
2  |     2     | 3 
2  |     2     | 4 
2  |     1     | 5
```

I feel I can do this with cursors imperitavely, looping over each row, keeping a counter that increments and resets as the "max" for each is filled. But this is very "anti-SQL" I feel there is a better way around this.

Comment: Why did you split `id=2` into four rows? Why not into three rows with `qty=2` in each row?

Comment: Thats not the desired output. Id=1 has a qty of 3, so it will fill the first bucket (bucket=n=1) and fill the second bucket (bucket=n=2) by half. When we move to the next row Id=2, we want to fill bucket number two completely.

Comment: So, the total sum of all `qty` (9 in your example) should be split into 9 / 2 (bucket size is 2)  = 4.5 rounded up, into 5 buckets. Right? And then, once we have these 5 buckets we can "allocate" ids to them if a certain bucket has quantities from several ids. Interesting...

Comment: Yes. In a classical programming language I would "go row by row, one quantity at a time, and fill a bucket until full. If there is still qty remaining on the current row, repeat process for next bucket, and do this for all rows" .

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, 1 as n, qty
      from t
      union all
      select id, n + 1, qty
      from cte
      where n + 1 < qty
     )
select id, n
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b3b97d695a253c1e362440d45259e9b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the desired result. I think recursion is required, but not in this implementation.

Comment: @starbyone . . . I fixed a very small typo and added a db<>fiddle.  This seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is recursive CTE which emulates cursor sequentially going through rows.

---

Another approach that comes to mind is to represent your data as intervals and intersections of intervals.

Represent this:

```
id | qty 
-------
1  |  3
2  |  6
```

as intervals [0;3), [3;9) with ids being their labels

```
0123456789
|--|-----|
  1   2      - id
```

It is easy to generate this set of intervals using running total `SUM() OVER()`.

Represent your buckets also as intervals [0;2), [2;4), [4;6), etc. with their own labels

```
0123456789
|-|-|-|-|-|
 1 2 3 4 5    - bucket
```

It is easy to generate this set of intervals using a table of numbers.

Intersect these two **sets** of intervals preserving information about their labels.

Working with sets should be possible in a set-based SQL query, rather than a sequential cursor or recursion.

It is bit too much for me to write down the actual query right now. But, it is quite possible that ideas similar to those discussed in [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/) by Itzik Ben-Gan may be useful here.

---

Actually, once you have your quantities represented as intervals you can generate required number of rows/buckets on the fly from the table of numbers using `CROSS APPLY`.

Imagine we transformed your `Quantity` table into `Intervals`:

```
Start | End | ID
0     |   3 | 1
3     |   9 | 2
```

And we also have a table of numbers - a table `Numbers` with column `Number` with values from 0 to, say, 100K.

For each `Start` and `End` of the interval we can calculate the corresponding bucket number by dividing the value by the bucket size and rounding down or up.

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    Intervals.ID
    ,A.qty
    ,A.Bucket
FROM
    Intervals
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            Numbers.Number + 1 AS Bucket
            ,@BucketSize AS qty
            -- it is equal to @BucketSize if the bucket is completely within the Start and End boundaries
            -- it should be adjusted for the first and last buckets of the interval
        FROM Numbers
        WHERE 
            Numbers.Number >= Start / @BucketSize
            AND Numbers.Number < End / @BucketSize + 1
    ) AS A
;
```

You'll need to check and adjust formulas for errors +-1.
And write some `CASE WHEN` logic for calculating the correct `qty` for the buckets that happen to be on the lower and upper boundary of the interval.